# EventLog Reader ignore system event tracing in C#

Tags: c#, trace, etw

I wrote some logs using event log and wanted to read it using EventlogReader in c#. How can I ignore system events in those logs. In c++, there are EventTraceGuid and EVENT_TRACE_TYPE_INFO defined in evntrace.h that can be used for filtering system event log, where EventTraceGuid equals {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3} and EVENT_TRACE_TYPE_INFO equals 0.
Is there anything similar to this in c#?

```
//c++
if (IsEqualGUID(record->EventHeader.ProviderId, EventTraceGuid)
        && record->EventHeader.EventDescriptor.Opcode == EVENT_TRACE_TYPE_INFO)
{
    return; // Skip this event.
}
//c#
using (var reader = new EventLogReader(filename, PathType.FilePath))
{
    EventRecord record;
    while ((record = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
    {
        //how to filter record here?

     }
}
```

Comment: This is a system service, not a language feature. The event log types and events don't change from one language to the next. There's no "system event tracing" type, there's a System event log and different event levels, sources and event IDs. `EVENT_TRACE_TYPE_INFO` is the `Info` level. If you want to read System events, you have to explicitly read the `System` event log. If you don't want them, just don't read from that log

Comment: I mean C++ define a variable for system event log' provider id, which I didn't find in c#. I don't want system log, but it's not a good idea to explicitly compare a record' provider id with {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}, and filter records with this provider id.